# laden vs. loaded

Tags: differences, american-english, british-english

I was justed asked whether it's a british idiom to say something, for example a car is 'fully laden' as in American English 'loaded' would be used.

Does anyone here know about this issue?

Thanks & greets
A. Payne

Comment: Please refer to the Help Centre about what questions are appropriate on this site: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Generally, the word "laden" is only used in the US in certain idioms such as "heavy laden" (which is mostly used in the sense of "beset by woe").

Comment: thanks for your reaction! So US would not use it colloquially? ... to describe a car as fully laden? thanks again!!

Comment: In BrE, you would not say the car is fully laden. Laden is a form used in certain phrases but the main difference is NOT BrE versus AmE.  Laden means there is a weight on top of something. It is also literary or journalistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm from the US (BosWash corridor) and I have never heard of a car referred to as "fully laden".  However, laden or lade are used in the US in other contexts.

A cargo ship would be referred to as fully laden.  The [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lade) says of lade:

> to put a burden or load on or in; load: to lade a cargo ship.
>
> to put as a load: to lade coal on a barge.

The [U.S. Department of Transportation, Maritime Administration, Glossary of Shipping Terms](http://business.usa.gov/sites/default/files/Glossary_final.pdf) defines laden as

> Loaded aboard a vessel.

Other uses of laden, as defined by [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/laden)

> carrying something heavy, or supporting the weight of something heavy
>   laden with: Passengers got off the train laden with boxes and
>   suitcases.
>
> heavily laden: trees heavily laden with fruit

A person can be described as "laden with grief", as HotLicks said in his comment.

In summary, laden is a very old word that is used in the US as a technical term in shipping and in a semi-poetic way, but not used for loaded cars.